# What mail server does Ubuntu have installed by default?

Tags: server, mail

What mail server does Ubuntu 12.04 have installed by default, or is there one?

Answer (score 6):

The default install does not include a mail-server.

The supported mailserver for Ubuntu Server is postfix.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about an SMTP, IMAP, POP, or other type of mail server? There are few that handle all types, and so you'll often need to install and run multiple different server applications, or tools to use with them, to get what you want out of your server.

Along with the previously mentioned `postfix`, there are also `dovecot` and `exim4`, which work well together, and you will likely also want to install `procmail`, and possibly `spamassassin` or some other spam filtering tool, to help filter and manage your mail on the server.